# Angular 5 + Ionic 3: Não consigo enviar cabeçalhos em requisições para API

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic3, angular-5

Estou consumindo uma API através de um método post e preciso mandar no cabeçalho o Authorization. Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
public post(resource, body, authorization = false): Observable<any> {

    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

    if (authorization) {
        let token = this.userStorageService.get('accessToken');
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    }

    return this.http
        .post<Observable<any>>(`${environment.apiUrl}${resource}`, JSON.stringify(body), {headers: headers})
        .map(response => response);
}
```

Mas por algum motivo o Angular não envia os cabeçalhos. Já tentei de diver sas formas, mas nenhuma funciona. Alguém tem ideia do que possa ser?

OBS 1: Estou usando Angular 5 e Ionic 3
OBS 2: Já tentei usar Interceptors e não funcionou
OBS 3: Já debuguei a request na api pelo Postman, por lá funciona certinho, mandando os cabeçalhos e tudo, mas pelo app não funciona de nenhum jeito.

Comment: Já debugou o código pra ver se o header está sendo preenchido?

Comment: Já debuguei sim cara, realmente não envia nenhum tipo de cabeçalho

Comment: Estou enfrentando o mesmo problema...

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi, o `HttpHeaders` é imutável. Tente dessa forma:

Exemplo:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

ou:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Comment: Valeu brother, mas já tentei de tudo nesse negócio, não funcionou nem a pau. Mas obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Mesmo utilizando o `append` do HttpHeaders ele retorna uma cópia que deve ser utilizada.

Por exemplo

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Agora sim a variável `headers` contém o valor desejado.

Espero ter ajudado.

[]s