# Maneira correta de passar headers para o Objeto HttpHeaders

Tags: php, ionic3, slimframework, angular-5

Eu estou tentando entender como passar `headers` da forma correta ao instanciar um objeto `HttpHeaders` no **Angular 5**. Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
postApi(body: any, route: string) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {      
      this.http.post(url_api + route, JSON.stringify(body), this.options)
        .subscribe(res => {
           resolve(res);
        }, (err) => {
          console.log(err)
          reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Quando eu tento instanciar o objeto `HttpHeaders` passando um objeto como está especificado na [documentação](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders). Recebo um retorno 404 (Na verdade a requisição foi feita para a minha API. Mas por algum motivo ou erro ela não reconhece a rota):

```
options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'x-api-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    })
  };
```

Porém, caso eu crie um objeto vazio e depois adicione meus headers com `append`. Tudo funciona perfeitamente e a minha rota é encontrada sem nenhum problema:

```
options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders()
  };

postApi(body: any, route: string) {
    this.options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.options.headers.append('x-api-key', `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`);
...
}
```

Então gostaria de entender se é um erro instanciar um objeto HttpHeaders dessa forma:

```
options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'x-api-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    })
  };
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/285777/angular-5-ionic-3-n%c3%a3o-consigo-enviar-cabe%c3%a7alhos-em-requisi%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-api?noredirect=1#comment583430_285777

Comment: Eu tentei e pesquisei por alguns dias. Mas o resultado foi: Quando eu uso o "append" no console de headers não aparece as propriedades adicionadas e tudo funciona. Mas não recebo os headers na minha API. Quando eu uso o "set" no console os headers aparecem, porém a minha API retorna um erro de Page not found 404. Não sei ao certo se o problema está na API ou no app angular/ionic. Porém se eu faço uma requisição utilizando o Postman e passando headers, tudo funciona perfeitamente. Como isso estava me tomando muito tempo e esforço, resolvi passar meu token via parametro mesmo.